# SQl - How to add a Total column and row to my sql result set

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to a "total" column and row added to my query result. How can I achieve it? This is my query:

```sql
SELECT system,
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN filename LIKE '0601%' OR filename LIKE '0401%' OR
                  filename LIKE '0901%' THEN
              (amt / 100)
             ELSE
              0
           END) AS ci,
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN file_date = '202112' and filename LIKE '0501%' OR
                  filename LIKE '1101%' THEN
              (amt / 100)
             ELSE
              0
           END) AS bi,
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN file_date = '202112' and filename LIKE '0101%' THEN
              (amt / 100)
             ELSE
              0
           END) AS ac
  FROM tab1
 GROUP BY system
```

and this is my result:

[image]

Expectation: Total row and column to be added and populated with sum
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Subquery Factoring such as

```sql
WITH t AS
(
 <your current query>
)
SELECT t.*, ci + bi + ac AS 'Total' 
  FROM t
UNION ALL  
SELECT 'Total', SUM(ci), SUM(bi), SUM(ac), SUM(ci) + SUM(bi) + SUM(ac)
  FROM t
```

Answer (score 1):

If it were SQL*Plus, you'd

```
SQL> break on report
SQL> compute sum of sum_sal on report
SQL>
SQL> select deptno, sum(sal) sum_sal
  2  from emp
  3  group by deptno
  4  order by deptno;

    DEPTNO    SUM_SAL
---------- ----------
        10       8750
        20      10875
        30       9400
           ----------
sum             29025

SQL>
```

but - not many people use it nowadays.

---

Apart from that, you might `group by rollup` which works *everywhere* (I mean, not just in SQL*Plus).

```
SQL> select deptno, sum(sal) sum_sal
  2  from emp
  3  group by rollup(deptno)
  4  order by deptno;

    DEPTNO    SUM_SAL
---------- ----------
        10       8750
        20      10875
        30       9400
                29025

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want amt column as total column in your result, You can add that at the end of your query. Else if you want the total as CI + BI + AC, You can use below query -

```
SELECT
  SYSTEM,
  SUM(CASE WHEN filename like '0601%' or filename like '0401%' 
             or filename like '0901%' then (amt/100) ELSE 0 END
  ) AS CI, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN file_date='202112' and filename like '0501%'
             or filename like '1101%' then (amt/100) ELSE 0 END
  ) AS BI,
  SUM(CASE WHEN file_date='202112' and filename like '0101%'
      then (amt/100) ELSE 0 END
  ) AS AC,
  SUM(CASE WHEN filename like '0601%' or filename like '0401%' 
             or filename like '0901%' then (amt/100) ELSE 0 END
  ) +
  SUM(CASE WHEN file_date='202112' and filename like '0501%'
             or filename like '1101%' then (amt/100) ELSE 0 END
  ) +
  SUM(CASE WHEN file_date='202112' and filename like '0101%'
      then (amt/100) ELSE 0 END
  ) AS TOTAL
FROM tab1 
GROUP BY system
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is having a nested select statement to grab your sums first. That way you can use the results for the total.

```
SELECT system, ci, bi, ac, ac + bi + ci as total
FROM(
       SELECT
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN filename LIKE '0601%' OR filename LIKE '0401%' OR
                  filename LIKE '0901%' THEN
              (amt / 100)
             ELSE
              0
           END) AS ci,
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN file_date = '202112' and filename LIKE '0501%' OR
                  filename LIKE '1101%' THEN
              (amt / 100)
             ELSE
              0
           END) AS bi,
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN file_date = '202112' and filename LIKE '0101%' THEN
              (amt / 100)
             ELSE
              0
           END) AS ac
           FROM tab1) t
      )
 GROUP BY system
```